# Find the point of consolidation in a graph using Python

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I have sales data for a product since its launch and want to find the place where the demand stabilizes. To get a better understanding of the demand profile I have plotted both the daily sales and the 7-day moving average:

Daily sales:
[image: Daily sales]

7-day moving average of sales:
[image: 7 day moving average of sales]

I was thinking of using NumPy's polyfit to estimate the graph corresponding to the data and using its derivative to determine the consolidation point.

```
x = data['days_since_launch']
y = data['sales_ma_7']
polyfitted = np.polyfit(x, y, 4)
fit_eq = polyfitted[0]*x**4 + polyfitted[1]*x**3 + polyfitted[2]*x**2 + polyfitted[3]*x + polyfitted[4]
```

When the value of the derivative is within a set threshold I can safely say the demand has stabilized. The polyfitted lines will look something like so:

[image: Moving average with polyfitted line]

I am not sure if this approach is feasible, however, so suggestions to other approaches are much appreciated.

Comment: 1- can you provide a toy dataset? 2- which specific issue did you run into?

Comment: @mozway I don't have a particular problem per se, but I am trying to figure out the best way of algorithmically finding the place where the graph stabilizes.

Answer (score 0):

Polyfit is not really suited for this task as polynoms tend to show wired behaviour in many cases (like large deviations from the data points at the ends of the series). I would suggest to use [cubic spline approximation](https://pypi.org/project/csaps/) instead that nicely can follow all kind of time series and provide a functional representation of the data points and  allow to calculate thresholds etc.

Comment: @Nechoy, CSAPS is able to approximate the function well - possibly too well in fact..but how can I use it to determine when my value stabilizes? It does not output a function I can take the derivative of, just lots of new data points.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question on how stability can be detected using cubic spline approximation: it's about discrete math. Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csaps
import numpy as np

x_min = 1
x_max = 40
rng = np.random.default_rng(12345)  # random generator
x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 60)
y = 0.1*x + 20*np.sin(x**2)/x + rng.integers(-1, 1, len(x))/100

step = 0.5
xs = np.arange(x_min, x_max, step)
ys = csaps.csaps(x, y, xs, smooth=0.5)

# discrete derivative of cubic splines
der = [(ys[i] - ys[i-1])/step for i in range(1, len(xs))]

# find stable intervals of derivative using moving windows
window_size = 20  # width of moving window on x-axis
window_size_s = int(window_size/step)  # width of moving window on xs-axis
epsilon = 0.4  # tolerance when derivative is considered close to zero

stable = [i for i in range(1, len(xs) - window_size_s) if np.max(np.abs(der[i:i+window_size])) < epsilon]
if len(stable) > 0:
    # found something
    stable_start = x_min + stable[0]*step
    stable_end = x_min + (stable[-1]*step + window_size)
    print(f"stability from {stable_start} to {stable_end}")
else:
    print("no interval of stability found")


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xs, ys, '-', xs[1:], der, '-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

orange: cubic spline approximation
green: derivative thereof

Printed output:

```
stability from 16.0 to 39.5
```

Of course, you need a definition of what stability means to you. In this example, the curve should be flat enough.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Is there a reason why I should not skip cubic spline approximation, and simply use the points I have (blue scatter plot) to perform discrete derivative `der = [(ys[i] - ys[i-1])/step for i in range(1, len(xs))]`? My data already resembles the graph "I am looking for".

Comment: Also, how can you generalize it to all graphs using the same epsilon? If you have a different graph with values way higher ranging from 1000-10000, you would need a different epsilon right? I want to have a method I can apply to similar graphs with values in different ranges.

Comment: You can not use the points in general, because they scatter around. Calculating a derivative won't give meaningful results without smoothening before.

Re epsilon: You could calculate the variation of the derivative within the sliding window and define stability as the *relative* stability. Say, when the calculated epsilon drops to 10% of the previously seen values, then you would say "it's stable now."